# How to Run two userform in VBA at same time without showing excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two different userforms. Both must run at the same time. Main Userform is to fill the form and another is showing the progress, when I save the filled form.

So that, both works parallel, I set .show vbModeless for both.

But when I open userform with help of MyApp = CreateObject (Excel.Application), form just disappear.

Is there any way, to run my both userform parallel with MyApp.exe